# How to write JPQL query with `COUNT` and `GROUP BY`

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

How write **JPQL** query  with `COUNT` and `GROUP BY` and get result as `Map<Integer,Integer>`?

```
public class CommentEntity {

 private int id;

 private int parentId;

 private EntityParentType parentType;

 private Long replyCounts;

 private String author;

 private String comment;

}
```

.

```
public enum EntityParentType {

 PERSON,
 EVENT,
 COMMENT;

}
```

I wrote **MySQL** query and this work fine:

```
SELECT parent_id, COUNT(*) FROM comment AS c WHERE c.parent_type = 2 AND c.parent_id IN (64,65) GROUP BY parent_id
```

[image]

but **JPQL** query is fail:

```
@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface CommentRepository extends JpaRepository<CommentEntity, Integer> {

 @Query(value = "SELECT c.parentId, COUNT(c.id) FROM CommentEntity AS c WHERE c.parentType = ?1 AND c.parentId IN (?2) GROUP BY c.parentId")
 Map<Integer, Integer> findReplyCountByParentIds(EntityParentType entityParentType, List<Integer> ids);

}
```

.

```
Method threw 'org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException' exception.
result returns more than one elements
```

below is fail too:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT c.parentId, COUNT (c.id) FROM CommentEntity AS c WHERE c.parentType = ?1 AND c.parentId IN (?2) GROUP BY c.parentId")
 List<Map<Integer, Integer>> findReplyCountByParentIds(EntityParentType entityParentType, List<Integer> ids);
```

.

```
Method threw 'org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException' exception.
No aliases found in result tuple! Make sure your query defines aliases!
```

I tried add `pacakge` to CommentEntity and also is fail

Comment: as per the exception there are multiple results(List). But the method you have declared has only one instance of map.

Comment: List<Map<Integer, Integer>>  is fail too, No aliases found

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One workaround is to use the constructor syntax as follows:

```
SELECT NEW org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.ImmutablePair(c.parentId, COUNT(c.id)) FROM ...
```

Of course, you could use any other class in place of `ImmutablePair` (e.g. a concrete implementation of `Map.MapEntry`). You then declare the result as a `List<ImmutablePair>` and collect the results into a map in your service method.

Comment: is there a guarantee that the values will set in the right order 'key' & 'value'?

Comment: Yes, of course. The above query tells JPA to invoke the constructor of `ImmutablePair`, and the order of constructor parameters is significant in Java